# Issues with getting item ID after clicking

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I've got my `data.json` list importing to this component. I've got it setup already using params to filter through the data to only show certain items. Below that I'd like to have it setup to where I can click on an items image, and then use that items id to show the new page/card with info for that specific clicked item. So far the way I have it setup it shows (example: url('/Food/undefined')). I'm assuming it should show (url:/Food/1) for the id of that image being 1. Does it need to be fetch or axios? I tried them, but didn't get anywhere since I probably wasn't using them right. I've been stuck on this for two days now.

```
import React from 'react'
import Data from './data.json'
import '../index.css'
import { useSearchParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Home() {
  const [ searchParams, setSearchParams ] = useSearchParams()

  const typeFilter = searchParams.get("category")

  const foodType = typeFilter ? Data.filter(item => item.category === typeFilter) : Data

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-center font-bold text-2xl mt-7">Food Menu</h1>
      <div className="italic text-center my-5 mx-8 font-semibold">
        <p>** All beef burgers come standard with lettuce, tomato, pickles, and onions. **</p>
        <p>** All chicken sandwiches come standard with lettuce and mayo. **</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button 
          onClick={() => setSearchParams({category: "burger"})}
          className={`filterbuttons hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 
                     ${typeFilter === "burger" ? "selected" : ""}`}
        >
          Burgers
        </button>
        <button 
          onClick={() => setSearchParams({category: "sides"})}
          className={`filterbuttons hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 
                     ${typeFilter === "sides" ? "selected" : ""}`}
        >
          Sides
        </button>
        <button 
          onClick={() => setSearchParams({category: "desert"})}
          className={`filterbuttons hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 
                     ${typeFilter === "desert" ? "selected" : ""}`}
        >
          Desert
        </button>
        <button 
          onClick={() => setSearchParams({})}
          className={`filterbuttons hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 
                     ${typeFilter === null ? "selected" : ""}`}
        >
          All
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap">
        {foodType.map(item => {
          return (
            <div className="menuitems hover:scale-[105%] ease-in-out duration-75 mx-auto bg-white">
              <Link to={`/Food/${Data.id}`}>
                <h3>{item.title}</h3>
                <p>{item.info}</p>
                <img src={item.pic} className="foodpics" />
              </Link>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just noticed something, in your map for your link you have to={`/Food/${Data.id}` should that be to={`/Food/$item.id}`? If you add what your Data.json object looks like that might be a lot of help to solve it too.

Comment: Man! All of that struggle and that shows my ('Food/idnumber')! Thank you! Then after this I'm assuming the next page is where I'll use fetch or axios to call for info related to that id number right?

Comment: Yeah I would make a custom data fetching hook. - Happy to make a quick codesandbox if that is helpful for you. Then that custom hook will take in the id and get the data for you and returns it.

Comment: Man I will take whatever help is given to me. Still just trying to learn a lot of this on my own.

Comment: Yeah I have been there and it is tough. Here is a really quick example I threw together for a quick custom data hook and the essential parts of it. https://codesandbox.io/s/customdatahook-m8vr5v